# how to create trigger in php and mysql?

Tags: mysql, triggers

when i insert data into **table1** below with data

| item_cid | item_id | item_name | purchase qty | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 407 | Tequila5 | 4 | 2022-03-11 |
| 8 | 408 | Tequila6 | 7 | 2022-03-11 |

I want to insert a default value '**0**' for each row of column **current_stock** in **table2** because it was null before.

| item_cid | item_id | item_name | current stock | purchase qty | total | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 407 | Tequila5 | 0 | 4 | 4 | 2022-03-11 |
| 8 | 408 | Tequila6 | 0 | 7 | 7 | 2022-03-11 |

Comment: Most likely you dont need a trigger it more feels like you are looking for the [DEFAULT 0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html) column constraint

Comment: Do you want to copy the row which is inserted in `table1` to `table2` with additional values for columns `current_stock` and `total`?

Comment: @RaymondNijland the both row to be created with the values after I insert it in table1

Comment: @Akina only current stock value  be set 0  after I insert values to table1